# Symfony unable to parse file vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Resources/config/dbal.xml

Tags: php, symfony, kubernetes

I have a symfony 6.4 project deployed onto kubernetes cluster which runs a docker container for the environment. Once the pipeline has pushed the changes, an error is thrown saying cannot parse the file mentioned on the title and reason is that the xml is not valid.

I've checked with online with multiple xml validation tools and the xml is valid, so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

I have no issues on my local machine, it works fine. It's just on the cluster I'm having issues.

Anybody came across similar situation ?

Comment: On the symfony's doctrine configuration reference documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html it mentions a xml namespace and xsd which is different than the one on the deal.xml file.